# TextField in UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, textfield

I'm new to iphone world .. help me out of this.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *MYIdentifier =@"MyIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MYIdentifier];
    if(cell==nil)
    {
        cell=[[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MYIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    CGRect frame =CGRectMake(5 ,10 , 320, 44);
    UITextField *txtField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
    [txtField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
    txtField.delegate=self;
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            txtField.placeholder=editFrndBDb.frndName;
            txtField.text=editFrndBDb.frndName;
            txtField.tag=1;
            break;
        case 1:
            txtField.placeholder=editFrndBDb.bDay;
            txtField.text=editFrndBDb.bDay;
            txtField.tag=2;
            break;
        case 2:
            txtField.placeholder=editFrndBDb.frndNote;
            txtField.text=editFrndBDb.frndNote;
            txtField.tag=3;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    [cell.contentView addSubview:txtField];
    [txtField release];
    cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    return cell;    
}


-(IBAction ) saveChanges:(id) sender
{

    UITextField *name =(UITextField *)[self.viewWithTag:1];

    UITextField *bday= (UITextField *)[self.viewWithTag:2];

    UITextField *note=(UITextField *)[self.viewWithTag:3];

    NSInteger fid=editFrndBDb.friendId;

    if(name.text==NULL)
        name.text=@" ";
    if(bday.text!=NULL)
        bday.text=@" ";
    if(note.text!=NULL)
        note.text=@" ";

    [editFrndBDb editFriendInfo:name.text frndBdayIs:bday.text frndNoteIs:note.text frndIdIs:fid];
}
```

getting error in saveChange Method in Statement

```
UITextField *name= (UITextField *)[self.viewWithTag:1];
```

error message : -

```
"viewWithTag is some thing not a structure or a union:"
```

help me out of this ...

Answer (score 2):

You are incorrectly using the property syntax for a message

it should be

```
[self viewWithTag:3];
```

not

```
[self.viewWithTag:3];
```

Comment: i have tried [self viewWithTag:3] but using this there is exception occuring.... at this line ..

Comment: you also have [self viewWithTag:2] and [self viewWithTag:1] change those also